# Receiving IOException

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm getting the `IOException` Error when I try this, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

[image]

This is my code:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(PDFFilePath(), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Where

```
private string PDFFilePath()
    {
        m_sFilePath = "C:/Pictures/";
        return m_sFilePath;
    }
```

What am I missing?

I'm using this `FileStream` to save PDF documents using the Pdf.Select NuGet.  It uses a method:

```
PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream);
```

Comment: C:\Pictures\ instead of C:/Pictures? On second thought, I think with that FileStream class, you need to specify a file rather than a directory. See the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried switching it to:

    `m_sFilePath = @"C:\Pictures\";`

I got the same result...  

I just need to designate a file path to save the documents to, rather than edit a specific file...  I haven't had to use `FileStream` since college...

Comment: That would be a directory name and not a file name.

Comment: "An I/O error, such as specifying `FileMode.CreateNew` when the file specified by path already exists, occurred." [From docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does the file already exist?

Comment: No.  I want to use the Stream as a directory to save new files.

Comment: I don't want a `FileStream`, do I??

Comment: I think you're looking for `SaveFileDialog` or some such :)

Comment: @GeoffOverfield It doesn't make sense to give a FileStream only a path - it's a File Steam, not a Directory Stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be specifying your path this way:

```
private string PDFFilePath(string filename)
{
    m_sFilePath = @"C:\Pictures\" + filename;
    return m_sFilePath;
}
```

Like @Reisclef said, you have to provide a file path, not a directory. Since you're using `FileMode.CreateNew`, it has to be a new file, so you might also want to use `File.Exists(m_sFilePath)` before returning.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here.

First, if you use a path like `C:\Pictures\`, it'll complain about the trailing `\`.

Secondly, you need to specify an actual file here, not just a directory. It makes no sense to just specify a directory (rather than a file) in this case - that's why it's called a File Stream and not a Directory Stream. I suggest using `Path.Combine` for this. Also, if you're just trying to move an already-existing file to this directory, you should do `File.Move` rather than using a FileStream.

Third, you only want to use `FileMode.CreateNew` if there's no possibility that the file already exists in the destination folder; if it *does* exist, this will throw an exception.

Fourth, it's a bad practice to hardcode paths like this. You usually want to get the path from a configuration file and make sure that the Pictures directory does, in fact, exist before you try to do this operation; otherwise it may fail when you deploy it to another machine.

Fifth, the `PDFFilePath` method seems rather pointless in this case - you can do the same thing with a string constant or creating a readonly string in the constructor.